# Error when setting MPI_Info: value is too long

Tags: c, mpi

I am configuring my *MPI_Info* with the hosts where the processes will be spawned (*MPI_Comm Spawn*).

The problem is that when I use a big amount of processes the setting is not performed correctly, throwing this error:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Info_set: Invalid MPI_Info value , error stack:
MPI_Info_set(117): MPI_Info_set(info=0x9c000000, key=hosts, value=cuda00,cuda00,cuda00,cuda00,cuda00,cuda00,cuda00,cuda00,cuda01,cuda01,cuda01,cuda01,cuda01,cuda01,cuda01,cuda01,cuda02,cuda02,cuda02,cuda02,cuda02,cuda02,cuda02,cuda02,cuda03,cuda03,cuda03,cuda03,cuda04,cuda0
MPI_Info_set(97).: Value is too long
```

The field "value" is the *hostlist* and this *hostlist* is assigned to the MPI_Info structure with:

```
MPI_Info_set(info, "hosts", mpihosts);
```

where "mpihosts" is a *char**.

Can I change the capacity of *MPI_Info*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking @francis' comments into account, I decided to give other approach to the problem.

Since `MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL` cannot be altered and `MPI_Info_set(info, "hostfile", filename)` is ignored, I must use `MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple()`.

`MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple()` expects a number of nodes and several arrays of that length.

For this solution I keep focus on the MPI_Info field, that now is an array which can be set like that:

```
MPI_info *infos = malloc(sizeof (MPI_Info) * nodecnt);
for (i = 0; i < nodecnt; i++) {
    MPI_Info_create(&infos[i]);
    MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", hostnames[i]);
}
```

- `nodecnt` is the total amount of nodes to spawn the new processes.
- `hostnames` is an array of strings which have the host name repeated (separated by commas) as many times as processes will be spawned in that host.

So, in our call to `MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple()` we will use the variable `infos`.
Mine is similar to this:

```
MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple(nodecnt, commands, MPI_ARGVS_NULL, maxprocs, infos, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &newcomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
```

By the way, it is true that this does not solve the problem completely, due to with a very long list of host names, we would get the same problem. However, this solution give us more room have for manoeuvre.

Answer (score 1):

**Indeed, there an hard-coded maximal length for the string describing the values in `MPI_INFO`.** It is defined in `mpi.h` and it is named **`MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL`**. According to the [MPI standards](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), at the beginning of chapter 9 (p397):

> values have an implementation-defined maximum length
>   of `MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL`... ... If either key or value are larger than the allowed maximums, the errors MPI_ERR_INFO_KEY or MPI_ERR_INFO_VALUE are raised, respectively.

Let's print this value: by trying `printf("MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL is %d\n",MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL);`, my openmpi value is 256... There is a line `#define MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL      1024` in the file mpich3-2/src/include/mpi.h.in of MPICH2. As a result, the list of the hostname can be too long to be stored as the value of a key in an MPI_INFO structure.

As an alternative, the list of the hosts can be stored in a file and the name of the file can be provided to `MPI_Comm_spawn()` as the value of the key **`hostfile`** of the MPI_INFO structure, as detailed in the [documentation of OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php)

Comment: Thanks @francis, I started to get deeper in the topic and I found out the same. Furthermore, I tried with the hostfile option that you propose, and it seems to be ignored. Please, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728334/mpi-comm-spawn-is-ignoring-mpi-info-set-hostfile

Comment: You're welcome. The other way around is to stick to the `host` key and call [`MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple.3.php) using multiple MPI_INFO, each one featuring a different value for the host, as suggested [here](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich-discuss/2006-February/001194.html).